# Getting length of an object property which is a property of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

So, I want to get the length of an object property which is a property of an array of objects.

I want to get the length of `actionDetails`.

I tried the following: `message[0].actionDetails[0].length;` but this is resulting in undefined.

The data goes like this:

```
message=   [  
       {  
          "data":"1",
          "actionDetails":[  
             {  
                "type":"action",
                "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/dashboard"
             },
             {  
                "type":"action",
                "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/dashboard"
             },
             {  
                "type":"action",
                "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/app\/dashboard"
             }
    ]
```

Comment: `message[0].actionDetails.length`

Comment: Try message[0].actionDetails.length

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the following: message[0].actionDetails[0].length; but this is
>   resulting in undefined.

Almost there, you don't need to get `0`th index of the array first whose length you are looking for

```
message[0].actionDetails.length;
```